# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: never invoked but rows and headers are > 0

Tags: objective-c, ios

A tableView in my UIViewController has as data source a NSMutableArray.

After I've added a new object to the mutable array, I invoke [tableView reloadData], which correctly invokes:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

returning the correct update amount of elements in the array. However the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is not called afterwards. I thought when I reloadData of a table view such method was invoked.

The sections method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
```

always returns 1, in my code.
Thanks

Comment: Does it _ever_ get called? Are you ever seeing any cells in the table?

Comment: @jrturton Yes, only at the beginning, when the table is initialized for the first time. But I don't manage to update the table when the array is updated.

Comment: Could you provide more details? It's difficult to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: I've set as datasource and delegate of the tableview the UIViewController class in which all this code has been added. At a certain point I'm adding objects to an array, and the table is supposed to be updated when this array is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a thread issue... Ive fixed it with:

```
  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 [table reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

method returns?

Have you managed it to return the count of your data source which is a NSMutableArray as you have mentioned?

In this method call :

```
[array count];
```

Comment: Ya, this is what I'm doing. It returns > 0

Comment: [tableView reloadData] method invokes the dataSource and delegate methods to be called. Can you show the code for this?